# OpenLdap - change/modify not working

Tags: openldap

I am on OpenLdap and trying to modify an entry via an LDIF with slapadd command.

```
#LDIF

dn: uid=ROOTADMIN,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: userPassword
userPassword: MyPassWord
```

But I am getting below error....

54a0fc8e <= str2entry: str2ad(changetype): attribute type undefined

Why changetype is not taken by slapadd command?

Also when I manually try to change the password on ldap browser I get following on the 
logs

```
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://<MY_MACHINENAME>:389
#!DATE 2014-12-29T10:14:16.930
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 8 - modifications require authentication]
dn: uid=ROOTADMIN,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword:: S2l0ZXNGbHk=
```

LDAP: error code 8 - modifications require authentication? Which Authenication is required?

Comment: No. I dont understand where the authentication is required? How do I authenticate?

Comment: Try this: http://serverfault.com/a/514873

Answer (score 3):

An ldif file like this (containing changetype entries) should be used with ldapadd, not slapadd.